# Why did the creator of prado create Yii?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii, prado

I wonder why the creator of prado created a new framework called Yii?

Wasn't prado the right way to go?  Does this mean that I shouldn't even consider prado over Yii?

Is Yii also component based?

Comment: Qiang has already answered your question, give it a read at this link: http://www.pradoframework.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=3815qkb2965i34kvdk84ig25l2&topic=11022.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yii is a rebuilt and redesigned version of Prado. Prado was slow and was difficult to widely use its architect. Yii was built with all those things in mind.

Yii is component based as well.

[**Yii, the new emerging framework for PHP**](http://www.phpmadesimple.info/2009/06/10/yii-the-new-emerging-framework-for-php/)

Comment: couldnt they just have recoded prado? do you really have to start a whole new project?

Comment: They could have, but nowadays companies will upstart something new to get it out in the open, spread the word, marketing reasons, you never know.

Comment: Yii is open-source, so in reference to selling the framework to make money, he did not. In other area's he may have.

Answer (score 4):

Those benchmarks are worth nothing. They compare Hello world apps' RPS performances, which are completely irrelevant for real-word application performance. Some guy however did performance comparison with the demo blog apps for each framework, and Prado came out to perform even better than Yii (even though probably not outside measurement accurancy).

http://www.devcomments.com/Blog-demo-benchmark-Prado-vs-Yii-to59461.htm

Yii seems like a marketing BS to me, with no real performance-advancement for most real word use scenarios. And without Prado's tag-based templates it's a PITA to develop applications for it, at least compared to Prado.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Yii claims to be component-based.

I think the benchmarks illustrate why Yii is attractive over Prado and most other PHP frameworks:

http://www.yiiframework.com/performance

Yii offer an order of magnitude greater performance, measured by requests per second, when you use a bytecode cache like APC.

Answer (score 1):

No framework will last forever. Technology changes rapidly, programmers can no longer stick to one language or framework for their entire career. Particularly when paradigms shift, it's easier to create a new framework from scratch. For instance, whereas Prado inherited a lot from ASP.NET, Yii is built on the MVC structure. The founder of Yii also implemented many good ideas he found in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same in features but Yii supercedes Prado in performance.

See http://www.pradosoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=11022.0

Answer (score -3):

They are not the same in features. As posted, yii does not have the powerful tag based page / template support, as well as html controller.

Comment: You is wrong.

Yii is an excellent PHP Framework and came to meet various problems facing the Prado.

Also, yes possess a good support templates, layouts, themes, etc..